# Slice index of variadic arguments

Tags: postgresql, go

I am using PostgreSQL as a database for my service, with a go backend.
After querying the database, I can access the rows with `rows.Next()` and `rows.Scan(XX)` :

```golang
func All(receptacle ...interface{}) (error) {
    [...]
    for rows.Next() {
        err = rows.Scan(receptacle...)
        if err != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
            return nil, err
        }
    }
    rows.Close()
    [...]
}

func main() {
    var myInt1 int
    var myInt2 int
    var myString string
    All(&myInt1, &myInt2, &myString)
    //all 3 variables are correctly set
}
```

Here, `receptacle` is variadic.
If my query returns two int and one string, instead of doing `rows.Scan(&myInt1, &myInt2, &myString)`, I am using the function's arguments `rows.Scan(args...)`.
This is perfectly working when one, and only one, a row is requested from the BD.

What I would like to do is to use the same process to store multiple rows :

```golang
func main() {
    var myInts1 []int
    var myInts2 []int
    var myStrings []string
    All(&myInts1, &myInts2, &myStrings)

    //myInts1 == []int{firstRowInt1, secondRowInt1, ...}
    //myInts2 == []int{firstRowInt2, secondRowInt2, ...}
    //myStrings == []string{firstRowString, secondRowString, ...}
}
```

**Is there a way to tell a function to use the index X of a variadic argument, something like this: `rows.Scan(receptacle[0]...)` ?**

My guess (and tries) is no, but wanted to confirm this hypothesis

Comment: For each iteration you need to initialize the values to be scanned into, you can do that in one place with the `reflect` package or you can declare an interface and have all your slice types, that you want to use with the function, implement that interface.

Comment: *"Is there a way to tell a function to use the index X of a variadic argument, something like this : rows.Scan(receptacle[0]...) ?"* Yes if the elements of the variadic argument are declared as slices. i.e. `func All(receptacle ...[]interface{}) error {`